# division by zeroin crystal report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

```
if {GetRepo_StockAsdate;1.CostPr}=0 then
    100
else
    (({GetRepo_StockAsdate;1.SellPr}-{GetRepo_StockAsdate;1.CostPr})/{GetRepo_StockAsdate;1.SellPr})*100
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correct, you are getting a divide by zero error in crystal. This is because in your code you are checking if the dividend is 0, not the divisor.

```
if {GetRepo_StockAsdate;1.SellPr}=0 // divisor
then
  // dont divide
else
  // divide
```